# Rails error: Unintialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nameerror

I ran into a strange error after using scaffolding to create some code. The following error now appears on any new generate or destroy commands.

`$ rails destroy scaffold Plugin`

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-rails-3.2.5/lib/sass/rails/railtie.rb:46: uninitialized constant Sass::Plugin (NameError)
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `run_load_hooks'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:59
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in 'each'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in 'run_initializers'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in 'initialize!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/monaco/config/environment.rb:5
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in 'require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in 'require_environment!'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:25
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error log, there are two options you may try:

```
1) Comment one line something like gem 'sass' in Gemfile due to name conflict of Plugin 
2) Configure Sass gem properly
```

Then most probably you would be able to run new generate and destroy commands properly.